# MobileSafari crashing due to excessive memory consumption

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, web-audio-api, createjs

I'm currently working on an application, that utilises *SoundJS*. I inherited the codebase after it was found not to work correctly on an iPad - the issue being it creates a manifest of around 16 MP3 files, totalling approximately 35.7mb. This obviously causes the iPad issues, and at 16mb it crashes.

The crash log shows it's due to the *Per Process Limit* according to the Diagnostics and Usage Logs.

I've done some digging in to the underlying structure of SoundJS and can see it's default behaviour is to utilise WebAudio, via a XHR. This is then parsed as an ArrayBuffer (or an array of ArrayBuffers).

At the moment this means that, after preloading, we have 35.7mb of data in ArrayBuffers - not good. This is **after** crunching the file size down! There will only ever be one audio file playing at any one time - and this is one file per section of the app; **apart from during transitions, where two may be fading in to eachother**.

**Is there an easy way to free the resources up from the underlying structure; i.e the ArrayBuffers?** As far as I'm aware, the previous developer did try using calls to the SoundJS `.removeSound()` method to free up some memory, but the results weren't good.

At the moment I'm looking at creating an object acting as a registry of all the filenames, and rather than loading them through a manifest - loading them individually and removing them as soon as they are used. However, I'm expecting this to cause headaches with easing one file in to another during playback. Furthermore, I expect that may actually result in a problem akin to the Images one where MobileSafari didn't release the memory allocated to image - even after deletion. (The correct fix being to reset the 'src' attribute of the image element prior to deletion)

**Does anyone know of a surefire workaround for loading such large amounts of data in a web app targeting iPad?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

testing SoundJS has shown some issues with iPad not releasing the memory properly.  Unfortunately from a library perspective, there isn't much we can do about it.

If you only ever play sounds 1 at a time, I would suggest loading them only as you need them and removing them after use.  The biggest issue you will find with that is waiting for sound to load, so you may want to implement a smart preload of the next sound you expect to use (meaning you always have the current and the next sound loaded).  In theory this can keep you below the iPad 16 mb memory limit.  However, if the iPad refuses to free up the memory, you may need to introduce some form of cache busting.

Another solution would be to reduce the file size through lossy compression, which it sounds like has already been attempted.

A third option might be implementing some form of streaming audio, but this is not something SoundJS can help with.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was beginning to fear; I think it looks like I'll have to try and keep 3 loaded at any one time and try and limit them to about 5mb each. Streaming through <audio> would be a good idea, but I think other platforms (legacy?) also require support. I may try and keep the Manifest to 3 files, and manipulate that upon section navigation events.